# Get Position of a String in a field with delimiters BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to get the position of a word in a field that has the following data with the delimiter as "**->**":

**Example:**

Row 1| "ACT -> BAT -> CAT -> DATE -> EAT"

Row 2| "CAT -> ACT -> EAT -> BAT -> DATE"

I would like to lets say extract the position of CAT in each row.

****Output** would be** -

Row 1| 3

Row 2| 1

Ive tried regex_instr and instr but they both return position of the alphabet i think not the word

Comment: MySQL is different from Google BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
select *, 
  array_length(split(regexp_extract(col, r'(.*?)CAT'), '->')) as position
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Instead of r'(.*?)CAT'), '->', i want it to search from another column that has the value = "CAT" but its not returning the same position number. Any idea why that might be?